# Creating a .rul file for topology in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, file-formats

How can I create .rul file for topology in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3):

In ArcCatalog, create a topology on a feature dataset in a database. In the New Topology wizard, when you're asked to add or remove rules, you can save the ruleset which will create a .rul file.
On an existing topology, just right click on it in ArcCatalog, go to Properties, select the Rules tab, and you can load or save a .rul file.

Answer (score 1):

**ArcEditor and ArcInfo only...**

Creating Topology (ArcCatalog)
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_topology/006200000005000000/

ArcToolBox Toolset 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000nn000000.htm

Useful PDF (for all the types of topology)
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/001t/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf

Exercise 9 of this PDF http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Building_Geodatabases_Tutorial.pdf will guide you through the process (9.3 version)